# Domain of the function $g(x)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{-\log_xe}}}{x}-\frac{2x}{e^{-\ln2}}$

Tags: functions

> What is the domain of the function $g(x)=\dfrac{e^{\dfrac{1}{-\log_xe}}}{x}-\dfrac{2x}{e^{-\ln2}}$?

---

I found out the domain of $g(x)$ to be $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, but the answer in my book says domain is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0,1\}$. I don't understand why my answer is wrong.

Comment: You want to avoid $$\log_1 e = \frac{ \log e }{\log 1} = \frac10.$$

Comment: The domain must exclude all non-positive numbers and must also exclude $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>0, x\ne 1$, we have $\frac 1 {\log_x e} = \log_e x = \ln x$, so for $x\ne 1$,
$$\begin{align}
g(x)&=\frac{e^{{-\ln x}}}{x}-\frac{2x}{e^{-\ln2}}\\
&=\frac 1 {x {e^{{\ln x}}}}-\frac{2x}{e^{-\ln2}}\\
&=\frac 1 {x {e^{{\ln x}}}}- {2x}{e^{\ln2}}\\
&=\frac 1 {x^2}- {4x},\\
\end{align}$$
so we must also have $x\ne 0$.

Comment: What does the parameter $a$ designate?

Comment: This domain calculator site shows that $x=1$ is in the domain but i am convinced with your logic.https://www.symbolab.com/solver/function-domain-calculator

Comment: @Dr.MV Typo, thanks - I fix....

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia Interesting. You entered the entire mess of $g(x)$ as originally given, I presume. The original expression can't have $x=1$, as the first simplification isn't valid for $x=1$. The final form above shows that the original function can be extended to a larger domain.

Comment: yes,what was wrong in entering the mess of $g(x)$ as originally given.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia Nothing wrong with it at all. If anything, it was a compliment :)

Comment: There is still one $a$ remaining.

Comment: @Dr.MV Darn, right you are, & thanks again.

Comment: @BrianO,this domain calculator is wrong?Isn't it?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure. ;-)) - Mark

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia Ummm, yeah that's a possibility ;) What happens if you ask it for the domain of $\frac 1 {\log_x e}$, I wonder.